# Jquery subtracting different values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where I have three input fields.
where if I input values anywhere on my textfield, it will subtract each textfield that has value to my totalNumber variable.

```
var totalNumber = 3;
var textFieldsLeft = 0;
var textFieldsHasValue = 0;

<input type = "text" id = "first">
<input type = "text" id = "second">
<input type = "text" id = "third">
```

how can I do with jquery where if I input something with input id ="first",
the  value of textFieldLeft will be = 2 and the textFieldsHasValue = 1 and for totalNumber = 2.

here is my jquery code

```
$(this).keyup(function(){
  countValue = $(this).val().length;
  //alert(getText);
  if(countValue != 0){
    console.log('Yes indeed it has a value');
    $(this).css(colorBlue);
    //alert(id);


    }
});
```

I need this to track down how many fields left that has not been filled out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a common class to all the inputs and then perform the aforementioned logic on their `change` event.

**HTML:-**

```
<input type="text" id = "first" class="inps">
<input type="text" id = "second" class="inps">
<input type="text" id = "third" class="inps">
```

**JS:-**

```
var totalNumber = 3;
var textFieldsLeft = 0;
var textFieldsHasValue = 0;


$(".inps").on("change", function(){
  textFieldsHasValue = 0;
  $(".inps").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() !==''){
       textFieldsHasValue++;
    }
  });
  textFieldsLeft = totalNumber - textFieldsHasValue;
});
```

**NOTE:-** Polluting the global scope is a bad practice, and should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you sir and for the note, I've tried diff solutions but yours only worked. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you didn't hardcode the inputs number in the variable but to find the `length` of the inputs in JS as well.

Secondly, I'd suggest you employ only one event listener, instead of listening all of the inputs (aka. [delegated event](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events))

Take a look:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="inputs">
  <input type = "text" id = "first">
  <input type = "text" id = "second">
  <input type = "text" id = "third">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var $inputs = $("input[type='text']");
var totalNumber = $inputs.length; //find the total number using .length

function checkInputs () {
  var textFieldsHasValue = 0;

    $inputs.each(function(i, el){
    if( "" !== $(el).val() ) {
        textFieldsHasValue++;
    }
  });

  var textFieldsLeft = totalNumber - textFieldsHasValue;

  console.log('totalNumber', totalNumber);
  console.log('textFieldsLeft', textFieldsLeft);
  console.log('textFieldsHasValue', textFieldsHasValue);
}

$('.inputs').on('keyup change', 'input', checkInputs); //add listeners to the parent div, but listen for inputs change
```

Also I am listening for both the `keyup` and `change` events, as a user may rightclick and paste the value without a keyboard.

The working example of the code can be seen here - https://jsfiddle.net/skip405/ouxdwjeo/

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all three inputs and then bind an event to the class
then, when one of the inputs triggers the event 
textFieldsLeft = totalNumber -1;
textFieldsHasValue ++;

```js
var totalNumber = 3;
var textFieldsLeft = 0;
var textFieldsHasValue = 0;

$('.txtbox').on('input', function(){
  countValue = $(this).val().length;
  //alert(getText);
  if(countValue != 0){
    console.log('Yes indeed it has a value');
    $(this).css('color', 'Blue');
   

    }
  check_txtField();
});

function check_txtField()
{
   textFieldsLeft= 0;
   textFieldsHasValue =0;
  $('.txtbox').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length){
         textFieldsHasValue ++;
          textFieldsLeft = totalNumber - textFieldsHasValue;
    }
  })
  console.log('textFieldsLeft : ', textFieldsLeft, 'textFieldsHasValue : ', textFieldsHasValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" id = "first" class='txtbox'/>
<input type = "text" id = "second" class='txtbox'/>
<input type = "text" id = "third" class='txtbox'/>
```

Comment: Didn't worked, it only adds the value, I do now realize the problem since it is adding up every time a press a key because of keyup. thank you also

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m4o34vLm/) . I've also added a `timeout` function not to calculate each time a key is pressed.

Note that I've added a `class` to each `textbox`, but that is not a must. Check it out yourself how you can select all of them without a `class`. ( it's easy )

```
<input class="fields" type = "text" id = "first">
<input class="fields" type = "text" id = "second">
<input class="fields" type = "text" id = "third">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "text" id = "first" class = "myclass">
<input type = "text" id = "second" class = "myclass">
<input type = "text" id = "third" class = "myclass">

  var count = 0
  var all_count = 0
  $('.myclass').each(function() {
       all_count = all_count + 1
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
              count = count + 1
        }
    });

var non_empty = all_count - count
"The total empty text fields are" +count 
"The total text fields are" +all_count 
"The total non empty text fields are"+non_empty
```